# active menu with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, menu

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav" class="span-15 last push-3 prepend-top nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="membership.php">membership</a></li>    
        <li><a href="../download.html">downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="../news.html">media center</a></li>
        <li><a href="../careers.html">careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="../solutions.html">Our Offerings</a></li>
        <li><a href="../about.html">About US</a></li>
        <li><a href="../home.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="subnav_about" class="subnav span-15 bg">
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Our Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="partners.html">Our partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="mission.html">Our Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="objective.html">Our Objective</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.html">Company Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".nav a").filter(function() {
    var currentURL = window.location.toString().split("/");
    return $(this).attr("href") == currentURL[currentURL.length-1];
}).addClass("navselect");

if ($(".nav a").hasClass("navselect") == false) {
    $(this).addClass("navsvelect");
}

var url = window.location.toString().split("/");
var e = url[url.length - 1];
if (e == "about.html") {
    $('#subnav_about').slideDown(1000).delay(200).fadeIn(600);
} else {
    $('#subnav_about').slideUp(1000).fadeOut(600);
}
```

In the above code, I m trying to get the URL and add class if current page is active.
but in the `about.html`, I am looking to keep the `navselect` also show the subnav.
if any click on the subnav, the subnav will remain open, and if the other link click on the main menu, then subnav will slideup then load new page.

I hope I clear my question.

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, maybe this will do the work?

put before js code:

```
var aboutSubPages = ["contact.html", "team.html", "partners.html"];
```

then change

```
if (e == "about.html") {
```

to:

```
if (e == "about.html" || $.inArray(e, aboutSubPages) > -1) {

    ...
```

Comment: thanks @denu :)     , how can I keep the class on the about.html, and add new class in the subpages of about?

Comment: you can try this: 

change:
`return $(this).attr("href") == currentURL[currentURL.length-1];`

to:
`currentURL = currentURL[currentURL.length-1];
if ($(this).attr("href") == "about.html" && $.inArray(currentURL, aboutSubPages) > -1))
    return true;
return $(this).attr("href") == currentURL;`
it's untested, let me know if that worked